# How do I get the foreground window from a windows service?

Tags: windows, service

I'm using some code like this [Get active window text (and send more text to it)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479548/get-active-window-text-and-send-more-text-to-it?rq=1) to send keys to the foreground window.  When I run it from the console, it works great.  When I run it from my service, the GetForegroundWindow() call returns 0 (zero).  How can I get the foreground window handle from my service?

EDIT: A little research tells me about services running as different sessions - if that is relevant to my problem, I need to know how to get the foreground window of the console (physical monitor) session if one exists.

EDIT #2: My use case only involves XP.

Comment: As of Windows Vista, there's no way for a service to directly interact with the console session.  However, you could launch a subprocess into that session to do the work on your behalf.  I suggest you start by looking up WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well on XP GetForegroundWindow will work if you set

> Allow service to interact with desktop

check box in service properties (Log on tab). This is NOT working on Vista and newer.

But you shouldn't do that, in fact you shouldn't call GetForegroundWindow from service, services run even when there are no users logged, and they also work when there is a more than one user logged on.

I don't know why you are doing this from windows service, but maybe simple desktop app hidden in tray will do the trick.

Comment: I'm creating a "keyboard wedge" program to get data from a barcode scanner and send it to other applications.  It's on a system that may have more than one user logged in, but only the user at the physical workstation will use the barcode scanner (sort of obvious).  I'm not sure what will happen if multiple users are logged in...  I thougth about just putting int he start menu, but was afraid if someone remotes in, the app will start on that session, which is incorrect.

Comment: It would probably be simpler to put the app in the Start Menu but have it check whether or not it is on the physical console and exit if not.  The WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId function should be your friend here.

Comment: Thanks Harry - that's great advice and that's the path I finally ended up on.